# no me muestra los datos en json con mysql

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, nodejs, json

No me doy cuenta del error o no sé algún paso más que habría que hacer en este ejemplo.
Tengo un botón buscar y tres etiquetas `span` para mostrar los resultados obtenidos desde la búsqueda, los traigo desde json a los resultados pero al hacer click no me muestra nada. me fije en `INSPECCIONAR` -- `CONSOLE` y me arroja éste resultado:

> verprontuarios.php:133 Uncaught ReferenceError: datosUsuarios is not
> defined
> at HTMLInputElement.onclick (verprontuarios.php:133:132)

Paso a continuación a detallar cómo esta el html

```html
<div class="jumbotron">                    
 <input type="text" class="mt-2" id="letra" placeholder="Letra">
 <input type="button" class="btn btn-success mt-1" id="boton1" 
  onclick="datosUsuarios()" value="Mostrar Datos">

 <h3>Datos del Prontuario</h3>
 <p>Nombre y Apellido: <span id="nombre"></span></p>
 <p>Hijo de: <span id="hijode"></span></p>
 <p>y de: <span id="yde"></span></p>
</div>
```

Esto es lo que tengo en funciones.php

```php
<?php 

if(!empty($_POST['letra']))
 {
  require 'conexion.php';
  $
  $query=$db->query("SELECT * FROM t_prontuarios WHERE id_prontuario= 
  {$_POST['letra']}");
  if($query->num_rows>0){
  $userData = $query->fetch_assoc();
  $data['status'] = 'ok';
   $data['result'] = $userData;
   }
   else{
   $data['status'] = 'err';
   $data['result'] = '';
   }
  }
  echo json_encode($data);
  ?>
```

Y esto en funciones.js

```javascript
function datosUsuarios(){
 var letra=$('#letra').val();
 $.ajax({

 type: 'post',
 url:'funciones.php',
 dataType: 'json',
 data:{letra:letra},
 success:function(data){
 if(data.status=='ok'){
 $('#nombre').text(data.result.fide)
 $('#hijode').text(data.result.fhijode)
 $('#yde').text(data.result.fyde)
   }  
else{
  alert("Prontuario no encontrado");
  }

  }
})
 }
```

Si alguien tan amable puede solucionar el error estare muy agradecido por aportar mi conocimiento.GRACIAS !!!

Comment: debajo del require en tu php tienes el simbolo "$" intenta quitando ese

Comment: negativo..lo quité y no me muestra nada

Comment: habria que revisar si tu archivo "funciones.php" se encuentra en el mismo nivel que el de html, de lo contrario encontrar la  ruta en el url:".../carpeta/funciones.php"

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: los archivos html y funciones.php estan en el mismo directorio, el funciones.js esta en la carpeta js/funciones.js me habia olvidado de ponerlo junto a los otros script pero ahora no me aparece en console el error igualmente al hacer click no muestra o no hace nada

Comment: prueba con `echo json_encode($userData);` despues del fetch_assoc

Comment: si puedes compartir lo que te arroja la consola seria de utilidad

Comment: el error que me sale lo puse al principio de la consulta

Comment: Habria que colocar la ruta bien de tu js que se encuentra en tu html, también coloca `;` después de llamara la función de JS en el onclick="funcion();"